# How to serialize dynamic form data to keep maximum UI flexibility?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Due to the nature of my current project, I often find myself having to create HTML `<form>` elements which must support dynamic add/remove functionality of items for posting collections to the server.

My issue is that I find myself constrained by the `name` attribute of the form elements because I have to keep track of indices, ex.: `Room[1].Tourists[0].Name`. This is giving me hard times when I would like, for example, to `remove` an existing `input` element from the beginning.

I am currently building these dynamic forms with `react.js` which is enabling great flexibility, but I was wondering if there was some way that I could collect form data on `submit` event and just serialize it to match the expected model in the controller's action and post it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you just want to solution about this i think you were stuck somewhere in your code that's why i am asking about the sample code no worry back to this try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_submit").on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Give URL here",
                    async: false,
                    data: $("#FormID").serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Do what you want
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        //Do what you want
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```